# .NET Core On-Premises Active Directory Authentication is Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, adfs

I don't have much experience setting up ADFS authentication in the .NET stack so forgive my ignorance if I am missing the obvious:

Using Visual Studio 2019, If I go to create a new ASP.NET Web Application with Web API, I can change authentication to "Work or School Accounts" and I get the option for On-Premises (see screenshot):
[image: .NET Framework Web API]
With this setup I only have to configure the app in ADFS on Windows Server 2012R2 and then the Federation Login page shows without writing any code.

However when using .NET Core Web Application and choosing API there is only option for Cloud:
[image: .NET Core API No On-Premises]

How do I achieve the On-Premises ADFS Work Authentication with .NET Core like I do in regular .NET Framework?

Comment: Is AD not just 'Windows Authentication'?

Comment: @OmarHimada This would be ADFS (AD Federation Services). It allows for Single Sign On. Windows Authentication would be different as it is checking the user account based off who is logged into computer.

Comment: Do you mean [Authenticate users with WS-Federation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @XingZou yes but that tutorial has WS-Federation as an option for logging in. In my case, as is in the OP, it should be both the default and ONLY login mechanism.

Comment: I just reported this to [Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/818478/configuring-security-for-local-on-premises-adfs-ac.html).  Feel free to up-vote this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a sample for .NET Core 3.1 [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/authenticating-to-active-directory-federation-services-adfs-2019-with-net-core-3-1-b0bf012fc183).